# how generate LIKE on arrays of values in where clause of sql query with rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an array of value :

```
words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

I want autogenerate a where clause with LIKE (and not "IN").

What I do for now :

```
words = params[:content].split(' ').map { |w| "%#{w.strip}%" }

where = []
words.size.times do
  where << 'name LIKE ?'
end

tags = Tag.where(where.join(' OR '), *words)
```

the correct request SQL is generate :

```
SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (name LIKE '%foo%' OR name LIKE '%bar%' OR name LIKE '%baz%')
```

but it's not realy nice way...

when I want compare array values with equals, we can just do :

```
 Tag.where(name: words)
```

There is a possibility to do same thing but not generate `IN`, but multiple `OR LIKE "%VALUE%"` ? How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In postgresql it works like this:

```
Tag.where("name iLIKE ANY ( array[?] )", words)
```

SQL RLIKE (REGEX)

```
Tag.where("name RLIKE ?", words.join("|"))
```

SQL select (not very efficient):

```
Tag.select{ |c| c.name =~ Regexp.new(words.join("|"), true) }
```

As a scope in Tag.rb (SQL)

```
scope :ilike_any, -> (words) {  where("name RLIKE ?", words.join("|")) }
```

That enables you to do:

```
words = %w(word1 word2 word3)
Tag.ilike_any(words)
```

Comment: There is a solution to RLIKE multiple properties like "name" and "description" for exemple, in same time?

Comment: Solved an intractable problem. Thank you!